# kendo combobox datasource filtering before bind is not working

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, kendo-combobox

I am working on a web application using kendo UI. I have a kendo combobox and binding via remote datasource. I need to filter kendo combobox datasource before binding.

here's my code:

```
$("#abc").kendoComboBox({
        dataSource:{
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
                read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
            },     
            filter: { field: 'Freight', operator: 'neq', value: 11.61 }           
        }, 
        dataTextField: 'Freight',
        dataValueField: 'Freight'
    });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MG89G/1493/)

Any help?

Comment: There is no field 'Freight' in your combobox, so you can't apply the filter to it. You are trying to translate the filtering of kendo grids to the comboboxes but the logic isn't the same. Also, the combobox has two fields: input and text. You are setting the text as 'Freight', you should also set the value as 'Freight': `dataValueField: 'Freight'`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.....No..the field 'Freight' is there that's why the data shows in the page. Please check my updated code in  http://jsfiddle.net/MG89G/1495/.

Comment: why dont you use server filtering instead ? filtering that much of data on javascript is too much

Comment: actually the above one is only a demo.I have only 5 or 7.

Comment: You should filter the data server side as I don't think there's a filter feature for the kendo combobox to affect its datasource. What's your backend code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed by using oData filtering.Here's my code. jsfiddle.net/MG89G/1497.